# how to run other php file when cake php project is on root?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a cake php project on the root of the server, I need to put some php files that should work individually.How I should do?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access your files eg with browser, you have at least two options here:

1. Put your file in CakePHP webroot folder, eg webroot/somefiles/test.php. You should be able to reach your script with yourdomain.com/somefiles/test.php
2. Assuming you are using Apache, configure virtualhost, and then reach your script using it. More info: [Apache Docs - virtualhost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#virtualhost)

Answer (score 0):

**Standalone Scripts run from the CLI**

If you want to know 'how' to do this in cake you should really consider using a shell if you are running from the command line.

[Using Shells/Console in Cake](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells.html)

Shells solve the problems of one off scripts that need to be run from the command line.

**Files Requested via the Browser**

If you are interested in reaching the file from the browser, I would advise you add the action to one of your controllers. Even if you don't want to rewrite the script into cake, you should still run the request through a controller so eventually, you will be able to port the script into cake. Or leverage any authentication or testing if needed.

If you have a standalone script that you want to load, make it into a library.

`App\Lib\MyUtility.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\Lib;
class MyUtility
{
    public function doThings()
    {
        echo "Hey I am doing things";
    }
}
```

`App\Controller\UtilitiesController.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
use App\Controller\AppController;
use App\Lib\MyUtility;
class UtilitiesController extends AppController
{
    public function doThings()
    {
        (new MyUtility())->doThings();
        // You can exit here or actually give some feedback to the browser if needed
        exit;
    }
}
```